# log4net writes to one file, but should to different

Tags: c#, log4net

I have two programs: program1 and program2 (they are modules of biggest program and could be run simultaneously), which of them use log4net.dll. Log4net.dll is one and shared between both programs. Each program has its own log configuration. Configurations are only different by logging path.

First path:

```
"..\Logs\Program1\Log_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log"
```

Second path:

```
 "..\Logs\Program2\Log_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log"
```

Here is an example of logging configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
       type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="..\Logs\Program1\Log_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger � %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Everything works almost fine, but sometimes program2 writes log to program1 log file. It looks like log4net.dll cached program1 logging settings, and when program2 asked to log, framework uses the same settings. Please suggest, how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you show how you are telling each program to use the different file?

Comment: I reformated question, please look again.

Comment: But that only includes the log for Program1. How does Program2 know to record to the Program2 log?

Comment: They are almost the same, except one line: <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="..\Logs\Program2\Log_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log" />

Comment: So you have two config files. I imagine both programs are calling XmlConfigrator.Configure(...) Is that correct? Because then whichever config got loaded most recently wins, and logging goes to that config's defined file..

Comment: Can the programs share a config file?

Comment: No programs do not share config files, they know nothing about each other, and their config files has different names.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the two programs to write to the same file, you should define loggers for each in their config files.

So, instead of just defining a `<root>` logger, define a specific logger for Program1 in its config, and the same for Program2 in its config:

```
<!-- program1.config -->
<appender name="Program1RollingFileAppender"
          type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender"> …

<logger name="Program1"> 
   <level value="INFO" />
   <appender-ref ref="Program1RollingFileAppender" />
</logger>


<!-- program2.config -->
<appender name="Program2RollingFileAppender"
          type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender"> …

<logger name="Program2"> 
   <level value="INFO" />
   <appender-ref ref="Program2RollingFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

Then, in each program, instantiate a logger with the same name, and it will pick up the correct appender:

```
public class Program1 
{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("Program1"); …

public class Program2 
{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("Program2"); …
```